# Let me see all questions / answers that point to a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, related-questions, linked-questions

When I am looking at a question and wish to explore the subject more, it is useful to look at all questions and answers that point to the given question (or one of it’s answers).

Please list them on the page somewhere, or provide a easy (one click) way of seeing them.

(A lot of pre-web hypertext systems had “back-links” as one of their building blocks with most links creating a two way relationship, this concept seems to have been lost in the web age.)

I have just change this to a feature-request, as I think a log of peole will find it useful to have back-links on all questions as standared.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20193/linkback-mechanism-for-questions

Comment: Take a look at my little project here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-what-links-to-this-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was implemented in [April 2010 with the Linked posts feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/).

When comments, answers or the question itself links to another question, they will both join hands and spot each other in the Linked questions list on the sidebar.

[There is an upper-limit of 50 links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section/48547#48547).

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with [Jared's sqlite datadump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21302/new-data-dump-in-sqlite-format-available). My link test uses pretty naive regex matching to find the most-linked-to questions, so the results might not be 100% accurate, but the overall direction should be correct.

According to this test, these are the 25 most-referenced questions on Stack Overflow:

- 69 links: [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711)
- 59 links: [What can I use to profile C++ code in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913)
- 58 links: [Hidden Features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033)
- 49 links: [How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557) ([now on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/))
- 41 links: [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166)
- 36 links: [Best ways to teach a beginner to program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088)
- 32 links: [What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644)
- 30 links: [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340)
- 29 links: [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394)
- 28 links: [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669)
- 27 links: [What are the best RSS feeds for programmers/developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119)
- 25 links: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748)
- 24 links: [What are Code Smells? What is the best way to correct them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342)
- 23 links: [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11)
- 23 links: [What PHP framework would you choose for a new application and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648)
- 22 links: [What is the easiest language to start with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769)
- 22 links: [Performance optimization strategies of last resort...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266)
- 22 links: [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556)
- 22 links: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073)
- 21 links: [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496)
- 21 links: [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873)
- 20 links: [Visual Studio Optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440)
- 20 links: [What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008)
- 19 links: [What is your solution to the FizzBuzz problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437)
- 19 links: [Jon Skeet Facts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223) ([now on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts))

Edit: What counts is a link from a question or answer to another question **or an answer to that question**, not counting links within a question/answer thread. Links from comments are not counted.

Edit: I have updated the list after removing a bug in my program.

Comment: Are these answers from other questions, from answers, or from the comments (such as the ever-popular **Dupe** comments)?

Comment: @Adam Bellaire: Good question, I've edited.

Comment: (sorry, I think we were tripping over each-other in the edit ;-p)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: No problem, thanks for the additions.

Comment: How many people correctly guessed the deleted question? :)

Comment: @Jon: Boat programming?

Comment: @Jon: Nope, I was wrong. I just hunted it down. Since when are the stubs of migrated questions deleted?

Comment: @gnovice - on demand only, and when the stub adds nil value.

Comment: This example clearly illustrates a topology and metric with inherently valuable qualities. It identifies a community and opens up the discussion to include multiple questions. It will persist in reflecting value over long periods of time because it is has slow growth. It is insulated from abuse by the effort required to add non-duplicate questions that reference another. I think that over a period of years this metric would be very valuable for SO and other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this the other day. It would be interesting to have a sort of graphical display, where you could zoom appropriately, but showing the interrelationships between questions. It would probably be more work than it would be worth. A simple list sounds like a good idea though...

Comment: a sort of graphical display could be done by a 3rd party based on the site dump as a demo for a graph display control