# "Unanswered" question sort order on profile pages

Tags: feature-request, questions, unanswered-questions, profile-page, sorting

To help users keep track of (and hopefully get answers to) unanswered questions, it would be useful to have an "unanswered" sort order on a user's profile page.  It would order the list of questions with unanswered questions first.   This would be in addition to the "recent," "views," "newest," and "votes" sort orders.

[image]

Comment: +1 I was just about to submit a request for this exact issue.  This seems to me like a simple request to fulfill with no downsides.

Comment: This doesn't have to be limited to *your own* unanswered questions, you could use it on any user's profile page (just like the current sort options).  I'm not sure if that's a huge benefit, but if you wanted to help someone (because you were impressed with something else they did, or whatever) with a (difficult?) unanswered question, then you could find it, for one.

Comment: I also want this!

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of `unanswered`? Questions that have answers but no one has been accepted? Or questions with 0 answers?

Answer (score 5):

Workaround:

Your own unanswered questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+answers%3A0

Everyone's unanswered questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0

Comment: Let me tell you from certain access logs I've seen: People are going to copy & paste this into their location bar, including "USERNUMBERHERE"

Comment: To get your usernumber, post a comment in this post and ask for it

Comment: @balpha: Any log entries [worth posting](http://serverfault.com/questions/115458/weird-and-funny-query-strings-and-urls)?

Comment: @Gnome: Not really, just a whole bunch of `avatar/HASH?s=32` from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) and `/QUESTION_ID` from [this one's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-a-tool-to-find-cross-references-between-the-trilogy-sites) first version. There where some cute "hashes" as unicorn requests, but making words out of hex digits isn't really new, either. My favorite was [DECAFBAD](http://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/DECAFBAD?s=128).

Comment: This gives me my questions with NO answers though. I'd like to see the ones that I haven't accepted an answer to...

Comment: @Svish - picky, picky, picky - try this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0 - Also, check out the search hints page, it has a lot of options that may tickle your fancy: http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: @Pollyanna: Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you have that many questions that are unanswered, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: I have many unanswered questions - I tend to ask difficult questions, and avoid accepting answers until I'm sure they are correct.

Comment: The number of unanswered questions is irrelevant, it's being able to locate them through the possibly tens of pages of already answered questions that's the annoyance.

Comment: I need to vote down this answer. Kragen is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked many questions.  I really want a way to be able to quickly float the questions that have not been marked as having an accepted answer to the top.

I currently have accept rate of 86% on SF, 3 of the questions 22 eligible questions do not have an answer marked as accepted.  I want a view to quickly identify those 3 questions so I can do something about them.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: @Gnome, I like it.  Even better is http://serverfault.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0+wiki:0 .  I still think that the it would be useful to have a link to this search or something on the profile page to quickly access this.

Comment: Bookmark it.  It's all discoverable from the search tips page, too.  In addition, anyone viewing this Meta question will be able to use those links.

Answer (score 0):

It would also be helpful to have an easy (i.e. easier than finding the correct search command...) way to find all of my own questions that I havent *accepted* an answer for.

Many times I ask a question when posed with a problem I cannot directly solve myself, but when I see the answer I might not have time to see if it works. If I can't tell immediately that it will, I don't mark it as answered, and before too long the question has fallen out of my mind and the author of the answer doesn't get credit for his efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you can post a question and don't get a good answer.  Then, after a while you find a good solution somewhere and it works, it is nice to post the answer to help others, too.

Sometimes you get an answer that didn't work right, but after few changes you get it (the answer helps you get there), but that is hard to remember after couple of weeks or even months (not my case at the moment, but it is nice to have it).