# I would like to sort questions on date of acceptance

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, sorting

*Please note that this is **not** about the overviews on user profiles; [there's a separate feature request for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60557/239016). (Several, actually, but I'm only linking to one).*

---

When sorting question overviews, I would like to be able to sort on date of acceptance, if any.

We currently have a number of different views on questions: newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, and unanswered. When searching, I can sort on relevance, newest, votes, and active.

What I would like to see here is an ability to order an overview of questions on the date an answer was accepted.

Comment: Would a data explorer query suffice?

Comment: Not really @Keen because I'd like to browse questions on the site this way. If I had a specific query, yes, but this is more for occasional browsing. I find that I would like to view questions on [skeptics.se] this way.