# What about add a "unanswered questions" tab to the user page?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, unanswered-questions

What about add a "unanswered questions" tab to the user page? So I can see my questions that are not answered easily.

Comment: This is something that I am, indirectly, proposing on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/help-us-redesign-the-stack-overflow-homepage/69073#69073)  You could do this using a saved search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we show a link in the profile to a user's open questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248408/282094)  
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36103/282094

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By your question, I assume you are looking for *your own questions* that need answering.

You can use the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to find your questions without answers:

> `user:me answers:0`

To get your questions where you have not accepted an answer:

> `user:me hasaccepted:0`

Comment: Great, thanks! Still, the button would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Who goes to someones profile specifically to answer one of their questions? Usually the "Newest" tab takes me to my unanswered questions. I don't think adding a new sorting category will add much value, if anything we need to get rid of "Most viewed".

Comment: I'm thinking about it for the user to see his own unanswered questions, which are not always the newest questions. I have really old questions that I'm still searching for an answer..