# Ability to sort by Unanswered / Answered

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting, accepted-answer

Hi, I like to have a high accept rate. This is in regards to our *own* questions. Not sitewide.

However, as I amass a significant # of questions I don't have time to fudge through the ones that still need a accepted answer marked.

Please add this feature.

i.e. to the: **Recent, Views, Newest, Votes** sorters, in our personal profile, by QUESTIONS. Add **Unanswered** . So I can see what questions still need a Correct Answer selected.

**UPDATE**: This is a duplicate. Of [View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unanswered" question sort order on profile pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a search [user:504239 hasaccepted:0 answers:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A504239+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1) to figure that out?

Comment: Nice one, wonder if it's also possible to sort by amount of answers?

Comment: This site never ceases to amaze me.