# Sort my questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unanswered” question sort order on profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages)

Under the **questions** tab on my profile I can sort my questions with these options:

`views` `newest` `activity` `votes`

Could we add another option called `unanswered` so that I don't have to scroll through all my questions to find the ones I haven't marked with an answered yet?

Comment: You're right, I didn't find that one before.

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can search for `user:me hasaccepted:0`.

This will return all the questions posted by you that do not have an accepted answer.