# Why there's no 'unanswered' order option in another user's questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unanswered” question sort order on profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages)

I am wondering why when I view another user's profile and go to questions there's no option to order his questions by accept. That is, question wihout accepted answer first, with accepted down. I think it could be quite useful.

Comment: *Why* would you find this useful? Not that I disagree, necessarily, but if you're asking for a new feature, it'd be helpful to provide some justification.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta because i find questions to answer with this option too. When I cannot find question to answer i randomly click on user's profile and go to questions tab and i usually will find something.

Comment: Just because there's an accepted answer doesn't mean you cannot still answer it. In fact, lots of votes == more reputation than one single checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't need to be. Just perform a search! When you visit a user's profile, the search box is automatically pre-filled with their user ID number. All you have to do is append a small snippet, and you can see all their questions which either have or do not have an accepted answer.

> [image: See the user ID in the box?]

So, just click in the search box and add in `hasaccepted:1` (or you can use 0 to find questions which *don't* have an accepted answer) and commence your search!

> [image: See your results!]

Visit the [search options help page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for details on more advanced searching. Useful here:

- `hasaccepted:0` - questions which do not have an accepted answer
- `answers:0` - questions which have no answers to them yet