# Can we have an "unanswered" option on the Profile > Questions page?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, unanswered-questions

After a while you start getting to the point where you've asked a lot of questions - finding the ones that don't have an answer starts to become a little laborious. I currently only have 11 pages of questions but this is going to continue growing over time. Some of these questions don't have an answer.

From a usability point of view, it would be nice to have an "unanswered" option alongside the existing "votes", "activity", "newest" and "views" options on `users/current?tab=questions`.

The way I would expect this to behave is that selecting this view would result in all questions that have not got an accepted answer would be listed, in date sorted order (newest to oldest). This would include any questions that have answers posted on them (regardless of the number of upvotes on the answer). Think of it as a checkmark filter.

I can't imagine it would be particularly difficult to implement and there's plenty of space to fit an additional button here without having to move anything around.

Would this be possible?

<sup>Note: [Something similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages) has been asked many years ago without defining exactly what was needed in specifics, and it doesn't have an official response from Stack Exchange on it, this is a feature request after all.</sup>

Comment: `user:me answers:0`

Comment: @TimStone "from a usability point of view" - why make it harder than it has to be?

Comment: @TimStone Considering that "unanswered" is not the same as "answers:0", that doesn't sound all too helpful. (*I*'m talking about the network's usage of the term, though, not so much the genuine "it has no answer", for which that, of course, applies.)

Comment: @TimStone your duplicate may well be a duplicate, but it doesn't have a red tag on it and no indication on Stack Exchange's thoughts on the feature request. Can we get on (on either question) please?

Comment: @Flyk Oh, I agree, I was just pointing that out. And I'd do something about the status of the request if I could, but. :P

Comment: @FEichinger Well, right, but I figured she wasn't really concerned with that definition in this case.

Comment: @TimStone I have clarified it all in explicit detail, just for you!