# Is there a way to search for posts linked to other posts?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, search, hyperlinks

Is there a way to search for posts that have links to other posts?

Say I have [this post link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004079/).

and I want to find all posts that have that linked in.  Is there a way to do this?

If I just put the number in the search, it only finds that post.  I want to find other posts as there is a lot of:  I saw this answer(link) but my situation is different...I want to find the "different" ones as one of those might  work for me instead of pushing in a new one.

Comment: I think it would be a very useful feature.

Comment: that'd be really cool, I agree :)

Comment: That's pretty much what my project at [HREF Overflow: A tool to find cross-references between the trilogy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-a-tool-to-find-links-back-to-a-question-within-stack-overflow) does. Is supposed to do, rather; it's based on the September data dump, so probably not that useful.

Comment: It's been updated now.

Comment: Of course, it is 5am and Jeff is busy tagging away.. such an odd sleep schedule

Comment: Can I just say that I love this solution/resolution, thanks for a very useful feature that I use often!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no built in way to do that.

Answer (score 9):

There's no built-in method for that, but you can find them if they're indexed by google by searching (using your example):

```
link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004079/
```

See [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/operators.html):

> The query [link:] will list webpages that have links to the specified webpage. For instance, [link:www.google.com] will list webpages that have links pointing to the Google homepage. Note there can be no space between the "link:" and the web page url.
>
> This functionality is also accessible from the Advanced Search page, under Page Specific Search > Links.

Comment: This will give a lot of false positives due to the "Related" column on the right side of a page.

Answer (score 8):

This is deployed experimentally to meta. Notice there is a new **Linked Posts** column on the right, above the existing **Related Posts**.

Linked posts are built by scanning all post bodies and all comment bodies for strings matching

`http://example.com/questions/\d+/`

Once "linked", the links are visible on both sides.

Comment: Sample: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634, "How are the rules different on meta?". 12 items in the "Linked" column.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46008, "Threshold for turning posts to CW Mode, on 8th revision or 9th?", has a link in an answer to meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740, "What are “Community Wiki” posts?". However “Community Wiki” posts?" has another post in the "Linked" column: "Losing my Way on the Meaning of “Subjective and Argumentative”".

Comment: OK, I got it. Editing meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46008 brought in the 3 outbound links in comments and answers. Now there is a Linked section in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46008 with 3 items. Ref.: comments to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40952/link-previous-questions-to-newer-duplicates/47803#47803

Comment: Does this work across sites?

Comment: @balpha not at the moment