# Double links in new "Linked" column

Tags: bug, status-completed

Do two mutually linked pages create double links in the [new “Linked” column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463)?

In [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) a link in the new Linked column on the right hand side appears twice:

[image: bug double link]

---

Another example is: [Is there a way to search for posts linked to other posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463).

Comment: That link is clearly twice as important as any of the other links.

Comment: For the record: I didn't do the "Fix this, Atwood!" part.

Comment: Do you fear his wrath?

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I like the new version of the picture that you made, but it could be misunderstood as demanding a fix here and now. Hopefully it will be received in the right spirit.

Comment: That *was* the spirit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory answer that needs to receive a few upvotes so the community doesn't bump it.