# Is Stack Exchange indexing with Google broken?

Tags: bug, hot-questions, search-engine, search-indexing

Today I tried to google an exact phrase from a question on [SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and received very interesting search results. I provide a screenshot of two googled suggestions below. Here are the links to those questions:

- [Cheese says "There was an error playing video from the webcam"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797366/cheese-says-there-was-an-error-playing-video-from-the-webcam)
- [How to use the msg command to send a message from one Windows 10 computer to another?](https://superuser.com/questions/1498918/how-to-use-the-msg-command-to-send-a-message-from-one-windows-10-computer-to-ano)

For those who cannot see image below: I got two links appearing as if they were asking the same question as asked on SciFi SE, but several years ago (2019 and 2016) and on completely irrelevant sites ([Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)). One of them contained literally the question text in full, another - only the title together with titles of other two unrelated questions.

The [question I started with](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277392/researcher-trains-a-mouse-to-be-more-intelligent-it-saves-his-life-and-his-fin) was featured in "Hot Network Questions" section, which probably explains my findings.

Is it possible to prevent indexing cross-question links by Google? This results in extremely unhelpful and confusing search results preview now.

[image: Search results screenshot]

Comment: huh, Its picking up the HNQs, That or SE got taken over by rodents. Also what the exact phrase is might help. For once, I'd ponder a screenshot of it for less than obvious reasons is a good idea

Comment: Us rodents have taken over the site since 1992

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike the phrase can be found in linked question, it was "Send mor cheese" with double quotes. I post search results as a screenshot, because those are not fully reproducible for different users. (let's hope comments are not indexed. and this hasn't added one more result!)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link, it clearly is.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtcNF.jpg no repro but I suddenly have this strangest craving :D

Comment: *"is it possible to prevent indexing cross-question links by google?"* Yes, SE could easily disable HNQ when the [user agent is from google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/overview-google-crawlers). Of course I'm sure if they do bother to try and fix this, they'll instead come up with some horrible way to poorly shoehorn ML into it.

Comment: [Cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_(software)) reference ([the tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/cheese/info) only has joke content). [Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_(disambiguation)).

Comment: The *"Related"* part in the right-hand column has the same problem: Much worse search results than otherwise (irrelevant search engines hits (false positives)). It has been like this [from the very beginning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts/41787#comment110575_41787).