# I'd liked to see a "linked by" feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to search for posts linked to other posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts)

Analogous to Wikipedia, I think it would be helpful to be able to see when someone links to your question/answer.

In form of a notification and/or in form of a page that lists the cross references. What do you think - would something like this be doable or at least useful?

EDIT: What I mean is a representation of site-internal linking that shows which questions the *community thinks* are related.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts

Comment: Wow, I can vote to close my own question, but I can't actually *close* it. Weird.

Comment: Yes, the concept of _ownership_ is quite different here, you can't even delete your questions if there are upvoted answers in it

Comment: @Downvoter: Well, it's not exactly a dupe. I am looking for a "push" feature, not a "pull" approach like a Google Search. I tagged it feature-request for a reason, this is not a how-to question.

Comment: ok, there needs to be 2 more close votes, perhaps it'll remain open

Comment: The other question asks a how-to question, but is tagged `feature-request`. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

A link-back list would not bring any benefit for the main audience in using the site IMO - if it would, it would have been asked for already. It is not trivial to implement - would bind SO developer resources for quite some time.

You can use [Google's "links to" function](http://www.google.de/search?as_lq=www.stackoverflow.com&btnG=Search) to find pages that link to a certain URL. I think this will do the trick in most cases already.

**Edit:** I didn't realize you mean SO internal links mainly. That I find not bad an idea (see the comment.)

Comment: No, it won't. It will not inform me when someone mentions one of my posts, and it will not improve the page value. A list of actual cross links on a page is definitely more helpful than a list of "possibly related" questions that, let's face it, doesn't work very well.

Comment: Hmmm...I find some really nice serendipity in the "Related" links. On the other hand my interest in a linkback feature is purely from vanity (not withstanding the risk that no one every links to my work ::begins sobbing quietly in the corner::).

Comment: So you are saying there would be no value in seeing a list of questions that the community believes are related to the current one?  I have to strongly disagree with you on that.  While I agree that this may not be trivial, but I also doubt this would be difficult.

Comment: @Zoredache I initially thought he meant linking in general, I didn't realize he means SO internal linking. Hmm. I can see *some* value in that. I still doubt it will produce many useful questions - as in "related to the issue of the current question". There may be too much noise. Anyway, I concede it's not an entirely bad idea.