# Add backtrack links to dupes from the original question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically track referenced questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/automatically-track-referenced-questions)

Could a list of dupes linked to the current questions be added to the side like the related questions list?

It would be similar to the "what points here" in Wikipedia, and would allow for [evaluation when deleting a question that has been marked as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post/46293#46293), but could conceivably have more uses.

It shouldn't stress too much the server if it is done denormalized and during the closing as duplicate.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-a-tool-to-find-cross-references-between-the-trilogy-sites -- but I agree with you; especially in the case of dupes, this would be really helpful.

Comment: Yeah, stress the server too much! I'm with you!

Comment: How should the evaluation work? All dupes get deleted or all dupes persist?

Comment: @Lady, maybe do nothing, but give tools to the deleter to evaluate what to do.

Comment: Closed? Oh, the irony!

Comment: @Andre Grimm: indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a certain question gets a sudden burst of activity, it'd be nice to know if there's been a duplicate question asked lately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the point to it, mainly because almost all duplicate questions will get deleted by the 10k users within a month.

Comment: Dupes shouldn't be deleted if they are valid questions (i.e. not off topic, real questions). If 10k users delete them, then they are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Ladybug: Dups *should* be deleted or merged unless they provide a more (or differently) searchable title than the original. Good answers to duplicates that are not merged and are not represented in the original should be copied to the earlier version. Otherwise you provide an incentive to ask duplicates rather than searching for an existing answer.

Comment: @dmckee: I took that for granted.