# Show count of SO questions that are referencing a particular SO question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks, metrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let me see all questions / answers that point to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21328/let-me-see-all-questions-answers-that-point-to-a-question)

It'd be interesting to have a count of the number (and list) of questions that cite the question you are currently looking at. That would create a "tree" of potentially highly related questions, and show which questions have spawned similar or related questions.

For example, looking at my question [how-does-one-add-a-svn-repository-build-number-to-python-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242295/), it'd be nice to know that there's a related question [how-to-programmatically-get-svn-revision-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499811/) that refers to it and builds upon it by  asking how to do it without the web calling Python/etc.

It could also be a valuable new metric for gauging question/answer quality (i.e. "4 questions cite this question"). I'd hope it'd be relatively easy to program - just parse all the questions for SO links and build a tree (which would have a nice visual presentation, too).

Food for thought. I'm making this a wiki in case someone has thoughts that run from this (or add appropriate tags).

Comment: Sounds like a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21328/let-me-see-all-questions-answers-that-point-to-a-question

Comment: declined as dupe

Comment: Oops - Apologies for the dupe - when I searched on this topic I didn't see the question John Smithers has linked.