# Please Provide a "Table of Duplicates"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

When a question is closed as a duplicate, links to the "proposed duplicate" questions are added to it.

I'd like to see a sort of index, or table of these duplicates. For each proposed duplicate question on SO, I'd like to see the list of links to the questions of which it's a duplicate.

This might help in locating frequent duplicates; in choosing the oldest good duplicate question; and possibly in creating FAQ pages on the subjects most frequently duplicated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. Do you mean to show the list of *proposed* duplicate questions before the question is closed? (Because obviously the list of duplicate questions is added when the question becomes closed.) Or are you perhaps looking for a reverse index, where you can see the list of questions that have been marked as a duplicate *of the current question*?

Comment: @Greg: No, I mean after the question is closed as "exact duplicate". What I want is something like a reverse index. However, I didn't state _where_ I want to see this list. I don't know the answer to that. It might be something in the 10k+ "Tools" menu. One might want both forward and reverse "indexes" - show questions closed as duplicate plus their proposed duplicates; show the proposed duplicates with their corresponding closed questions.

Comment: I like this idea.
See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21328/let-me-see-all-questions-answers-that-point-to-a-question
and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-a-tool-to-find-links-back-to-a-question-within-stack-overflow

Comment: This also relates to earlier proposals to create tag-specific FAQ documents, which would presumably be found by the search features that most users don't use.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/36650#36650 for my answer on the per-tag FAQ proposal.

Answer (score 5):

This is deployed experimentally to meta. Notice there is a new **Linked Posts** column on the right, above the existing **Related Posts**.

Linked posts are built by scanning all post bodies and all comment bodies for strings matching

`http://example.com/questions/\d+/`

Once "linked", the links are visible on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I like it so far.

Comment: So is this still in the works? I rely heavily on the "Linked" and "Related" lists as well as enjoy browsing the "Hot Network Questions" and even occasionally clicking on them. But I would love a "Duplicates" list on questions closed as duplicates, showcasing a quick survey of [the potentially infinite linked list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280249/321521). At least a direct link to the root duplicate.