# Separate "Duplicates" section instead of "Links"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions

I know the ["Links" section is recommended to track duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36366/please-provide-a-table-of-duplicates), but I feel it doesn't go far enough because it doesn't list all the duplicates, and moreover, it makes it hard to find *the* question.

Rather than link two questions together, a real *duplicate link* should add the question to a group of duplicates. Whenever a question is a member of such a duplicate group, all other duplicates would be listed in the right pane, along with the question vote count, sorted by the votes.

**Advantages:**

- Easy navigation among duplicates
- Extra incentive for voting on questions
- Extra incentive for properly linking real duplicates ([example of unlinked that would benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258711/storing-images-in-db-is-good-or-not))
- Better motivation for only closing as *exact duplicate* when a question is an *exact duplicate* and not merely *somewhat related*.

**Disadvantages:**

- significant implementation effort

**Example:**

Example of a question that would benefit: [What programming language for a beginner? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468054/what-programming-language-for-a-beginner)

The Linked section contains a **single** other duplicate (out of 12 links, i.e. <10% signal to noise), and then recursively apply this algorithm. After a while I discovered these duplicates:

- [Language for non-programmers to start learning programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419959/language-for-non-programmers-to-start-learning-programming)
- [Which language to choose to learn the basics of programming? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031197/which-language-to-choose-to-learn-the-basics-of-programming)
- [what programming language to learn, php, asp.net or jsp? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213822/what-programming-language-to-learn-php-asp-net-or-jsp)
- [Recommendations for a language for a non-professional beginner [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429608/recommendations-for-a-language-for-a-non-professional-beginner)
- [What is a good programming language for beginners? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990157/what-is-a-good-programming-language-for-beginners)
- [Best language for a non-programmer tech support person to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177660/best-language-for-a-non-programmer-tech-support-person-to-learn)
- [What language is best for a beginner to learn? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190957/what-language-is-best-for-a-beginner-to-learn)
- [What is the easiest language to start with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769/easiest-language-to-start-with)

At which point I started to get lost in my recursive search, because I kept stumbling across questions I've already found and the signal-to-noise (w.r.t duplicates!) in the Linked section was consistently very low.

This feature would have encouraged people to *actually use the duplicates* rather than re-ask a question after stumbling across one like this one.

**Notes:**

- I'm not suggesting that the Link section should go. I'm just saying its purpose is orthogonal (but superficially similar) to linking duplicates together.

Comment: The "duplicate section" is an interesting idea, but a note. [The linked section](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/) isn't just for Duplicates, but [for anything related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/automatically-track-referenced-questions) [that gets linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts). A lot of us use it, especially in Metas here and in SE2.0, to give quick access to non-dupe related conversations from the past. It's very convenient for that.

Comment: @(Grace Note) I got the wrong impression about what Linked was trying to address then, but I'm certainly not suggesting that it be removed :)

Comment: @Grace Note thanks; I thought the opposite used to be the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really help if "status-declined" came with comments. Even connect.microsoft.com posts comments for their "closed" results.

Answer (score 1):

Links was not created to list duplicates.

It's for questions that are *linked* to the current question in either direction.

> The **Linked** sidebar is very straightforward: it gathers up any links to this question provided by the community via comments, answers, or questions, and presents them in simple list format on the right-hand side of the question. It’s important to note that these links are bi-directional — that is, if another question links to this one, the link will be listed on both questions.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/

Comment: This answer does not address the feature request in any way (not even the subject line). Perhaps you meant to post this as a comment?