# Is there a limit on the number of Links that show up in the Linked section?

Tags: support, status-completed, linked-questions

As the title. I was looking at the [rules on Meta FAQ proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta), which will now be a great place to link when people are confused about downvotes on Meta. Or a place to link when you assume people don't know about downvotes on Meta.

In any case, the new Linked section is nice that it links not just forward links, but back links as well. To wit, each time these questions pop up in comments and someone links in response, said question will get another entry on its Linked section. So that list will be quite long in time... which made me curious... is there a limit? Not suggesting there be one, just wanting to know.

Comment: I must admit until reading this I didn't know how the "Linked" questions were chosen (not having seen http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/whoa-what-is-this-linked-thing).

Comment: Not sure if there's a limit, but if there is, it's pretty high. I've been spamming a link to tag synonyms in many retag-request questions where appropriate. Check out the Linked section there :D http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms

Comment: My, that *is* quite a large list there. From that, I can guess that there probably isn't a limit, but I'll wait for an answer to that.

Comment: Yeah. There probably *should* be a limit, or at least put the Linked links in a collapsible <div> so it doesn't take up the whole page. That section will only grow over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now an upper limit of 50 links in the "Related Links" section and they are ordered by a variant of [the existing hotness algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

Answer (score 2):

Query on the [HREF Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/href-overflow-a-tool-to-find-cross-references-between-the-trilogy-sites) database (April datadump):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num, ToQuestionId, ToSite
  FROM Links WHERE ToSite = FromSite
  GROUP BY ToQuestionId, ToSite ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
282|1732348|so
```

(number of SO-internal outbound links from that question: 3).

JavaScript command on that [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/):

```
>>> $(".linked").find("a").length
300
```

So: I guess no (or possibly 300).