# Links to current question - add "Back links" section or merge them into "Related" section

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, related-questions

Right now we have "Linked" and "Related" sections in the right sidebar. They are very useful. Unfortunately, there is no way to find questions, which refers to current one. Such questions often discuss similar problems or other things, which I may be interested in.

I think that showing such questions will be a useful feature. They can be showed in "Related" section or in separate section.

Comment: The "linked" section shows links *to and from* this question

Comment: testing backlinks - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section

Comment: it works, so voted to close as duplicate

Comment: I would recommend voting to close as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/ instead.

Comment: @balpha Strange. I was definitely sure that it's not implemented. May be link that I look was malformed.

Comment: Should I delete this question then?

Comment: +1 because this question shows up when using the section titles "Linked" and "Related" and let my find http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/automatically-track-referenced-questions