# Is the "linked" column still relevant for highly linked questions?

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions

Questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware) or the FAQ questions on meta (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)) are highly linked.

This is a good thing, but on the questions themselves, the "linked" column is starting to take a lot of space, and nothing seems to be there to stop it.

The linked column has a point for most questions, but for these ones, it's only a series of links which is not usable, and has finally poor interest. Also, it pushes the "Related" questions far to the bottom.

Should there be a system to "collapse" this list when there is like more than 15-20 links? Like displaying the 15-20, then a "show more"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on the number of Links that show up in the Linked section?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section)

Answer (score 1):

> the "linked" column is starting to take a lot of space, and nothing seems to be there to stop it.

see [comment on blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/#comment-46319):

> We now cap it at 50 and it uses a variant of the standard hot sorting algorithm to put the “best” linked posts at the top (score, # answers, # views, answer scores)

Comment: 50 still seems a bit too much. I mean, who will want to find a link between 50 others?

Comment: Also, if I understand, now we should also follow the comments on every blog post, to be aware of changes? :-]

Comment: @Gnoupi A linked question limit was [asked and answered before the blog note](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section)

Comment: @ccomet - indeed, haven't found this duplicate. Guess I should have checked the "related" column. Voting to close my own question as duplicate.

Comment: @Gnoupi Hah, I wasn't bringing it up to call it a duplicate, merely to point out it was announced. But I'll toss in my own vote to help you close. While I'm at it, I'll check to see if our [unofficial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/ "Oh snap this word actually links to Welbog!") [changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new/47815#47815) has this listed (oh hey it is).

Comment: @ccomet - 50 is still too much in my opinion, but I guess it's not enough a concern to justify this question in itself. Hence the duplicate vote.