# What is the most-linked question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

I went through a couple pages of search here on Meta, and I couldn't find a similar question.

Completely out of curiosity, what question on Stack Overflow has the most other questions in the "Linked" section on the right?

<sub>(And will this discussion result in a positive feedback loop that pushes the question's links further past all others?)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In April, it was [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) (see  [Is there a limit on the number of Links that show up in the Linked section?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section/48117#48117)) – I'm pretty sure this hasn't changed.

Comment: It makes sense that what is probably the most viewed question is also probably the most linked.  Thanks!

Comment: coincidentally is has the most upvoted answer in the history of SO...